# Insecure connection error with firebase deployment

Tags: javascript, firebase, insecure-connection

Actually, I deployed a website through Firebase and it was successful. Then there was nothing in the website .the website is www.novusorg.com The website is just about the organization. But now I added a registration form for the website. The registration form in HTML with ids is connected with JavaScript. And I deployed it again. But now when I try to open the website it says insecure connection. Please help me with the error.

EMERGENCY 
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE
website: www.novusorg.com

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "novuxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://novusxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "novxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //reference messages collection
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');

document.getElementById('registrationform1').addEventListener('submit',submitform);

function submitform(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var regname = getInputVal('regname');
var regmail = getInputVal('regmail');
var regregnum = getInputVal('regregnum');
var regnumber = getInputVal('regnumber');
var regcourse = getInputVal('regcourse');
var regreason = getInputVal('regreason');
var regfd= getInputVal('regfd');
var regbd = getInputVal('regbd');
var regad = getInputVal('regad');
var regiod = getInputVal('regiod');
var reguxd = getInputVal('reguxd');
var regpty = getInputVal('regpty');
var reggfd = getInputVal('reggfd');
var regved = getInputVal('regved');
var regfa = getInputVal('regfa');
var regcw = getInputVal('regcw');
var regmt = getInputVal('regmt');
var regem = getInputVal('regem');

saveMessage(regname,regmail,regregnum,regnumber,regcourse,regreason,regfd,regbd,regad,regiod,reguxd,regpty,reggfd,regved,regfa,regcw,regmt,regem);

document.querySelector('.regalert').style.display='block';
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.regalert').style.display='none';
},3000);

document.getElementById('registrationform1').reset();
}

function getInputVal(id) {
return document.getElementById(id).value;   
}


function saveMessage(regname,regmail,regregnum,regnumber,regcourse,regreason,regfd,regbd
, regad,regiod,reguxd,regpty,reggfd,regved,regfa,regcw,regmt,regem) {
var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
newMessageRef.set({
    regname:regname,
    regmail:regmail,
    regregnum:regregnum,
    regnumber:regnumber,
    regcourse:regcourse,
    regreason:regreason,
    regfd:regfd,
    regbd:regbd,
    regad:regad,
    regiod:regiod,
    reguxd:reguxd,
    regpty:regpty,
    reggfd:reggfd,
    regved:regved,
    regfa:regfa,
    regcw:regcw,
    regmt:regmt,
    regem:regem
});
}
```

Comment: When I go to www.novusorg.com now it shows up fine without any cert warnings.

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out. But Im not able to receive the data in the database. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your landing page on the website, I instead see a Google Docs page.

Comment: https://novusbetaproject.firebaseapp.com/    this is the website. And even im not able to save the data in firebase database

Comment: Okay. But when I tried to visit the website it is clean. Doesn't give me any HTTPS warnings/errors at my end.

Comment: that is not through the domain. But the error remains with novusorg.com. we redirected www.novusorg.com to google forms. and https://novusbetaproject.firebaseapp.com/ this is from firebase and just novusorg.com has the problem.

Comment: Even the firebaseapp link too works fine for me. Try other browsers